# Remove libvirt's dhcp lease entry using virsh

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, dnsmasq, virsh

Using:

```
$ virsh version
 Compiled against library: libvirt 1.3.1
 Using library: libvirt 1.3.1
 Using API: QEMU 1.3.1
 Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.5.0
$
$
$ lsb_release -a
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
 Release:   16.04
 Codename:  xenial
```

I'd like to remove a libvirt's dhcp lease entry using virsh.

```
$ virsh net-list
Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
default              active     yes           yes
docker-machines      active     yes           yes

$ virsh net-dhcp-leases docker-machines
Expiry Time          MAC address        Protocol  IP address               Hostname        Client ID or DUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-10 16:15:38  52:54:00:8e:15:f5  ipv4      192.168.42.22/24         minikubecluster ff:c2:72:f6:09:00:02:00:00:ab:11:af:a8:d1:af:21:23:5c:49
2017-05-10 16:09:57  52:54:00:c6:51:45  ipv4      192.168.42.23/24         registry        01:52:54:00:c6:51:45
```

I've tried different option using `virsh net-update delete`, but I keep getting this errors:

```
couldn't locate a matching dhcp host entry in network 'docker-machines'
```

Is this because libvirt's lease files are changed (they are named after the network interface and the format is JSON)? If so, how can I then do this then?

Answer (score 0):

The delete sub-command works the same way as the add sub-command.

```
virsh net-update docker-machines delete ip-dhcp-host \
"<host mac='52:54:00:8e:15:f5' \
name='minikubecluster' ip='192.168.42.22' />" \
--live --config
```

[Libvirt - Networking - virsh net-update](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#virsh_net-update)

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Is it listed in the XML configuration file? `sudo virsh net-edit docker-machines`

Comment: No, it isn't listed.

Comment: That's why you're getting that message then. There is no entry in your configuration file. There's no reason to remove it.

Comment: This does not remove the value from `virsh net-dhcp-leases`.